An expected value problem with an infinite range of values
There is a box with n items, numbered in series from 1 to n (here, n is not known). I pick an item from it and the serial number of it is x (1 ≤ x ≤ n). Thus, what is the expected value of n, the total number of items?
This problem is largely based on the Numberphile Counting Tanks video according to which, the answer should be 2x - 1.
If I begin to manually calculate the expectation value for n, I will need to be able to calculate the probability that y (≥ x) is the total number of items, which cannot be calculated. Thus, I am wondering if the expected value can be calculated at all.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@JoséCarlosSantos Hi, I am aware that Math SE uses LaTeX, but I did not find it necessary in this question, since I am admittedly lazy to pick that skill up as a casual math enthusiast.

Use Bayes theorem to work out "likelihood of $n = n_0$ given that $x$ was seen" from "likelihood $x$ is seen if $n = n_0$."

The value of $n$ that maximizes the probability of drawing the number $x$ is $n=x$. If you want a posterior distribution for $n$ in order to calculate an expected value, then you need to choose a prior distribution (which will necessarily encode some bias towards certain values of $n$, since there is no uniform distribution on $\Bbb N$).
